# How to periodically update content in Win 8.1 app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, periodic-task

How can I periodically update (i.e. all 10s) a class in my ViewModel by call an async Webservice call in a Win 8.1 Universal app? 
I tried with a DispatcherTimer but the timer can't handle the async part.
Here is my code i tried:

```
_myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
_myTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
_myTimer.Tick += timerTick;

protected async Task timerTick(object sender, object e)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);

    string url = "url";

    using (Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(url)))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't access your ViewModel from the background task. You subscribe to the background workers' "completed" event in your view model and do the update in the handler.

Comment: can you show me an example, how to handle this?

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: BackgroundWorker is not available in Win 8.1 Universal app. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Ah. You can implement the functionality yourself, but it's a long time since I had to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct. DispatcherTimer is a particular timer that can manipulate UI Thread (instead of Timer class which runs on another thread).

What do you want to mean with:

```
the timer can't handle the async part
```

Thanks!

Comment: my problem is the outputtype from the timerTick event. Because my return is a Task, but I can't handle it like this: _myTimer.Tick += await timerTick;

Comment: You don't have to await the output of the Tick event.
Just await the needed method calls in the event handler.